# how to log the user in Directus from a different domain and login form then authenticate him in the Directus admin page

Tags: python, django, authentication, directus

now I have created a `Directus` application, and am using it as a back-end .. and am letting the user log in from another external domain and form `Django` app and sending post request to be able to login .. how to stop `Derictus` from asking him to log in again after i redirect him to the Directus admin panel link after login success ?

here are some of the codes I have used for the whole process :

**docekr-compose.yaml** for the `Directus` part :

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: ${DB_IMAGE}
    container_name: ${DB_CONTAINER_NAME}
    volumes:
      - ${DB_VOLUME}
    ports:
      - '${DB_PORT}:5432'
    restart: always       
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_DATABASE}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      # - PGDATA=/tmp

  directus:
    image: directus/directus:10.7.1
    container_name: ${WEB_CONTAINER_NAME}
    ports:
      - ${APP_PORT}:8055
    restart: always  
    volumes:
      - ./uploads:/directus/uploads
    environment:
      KEY: ${KEY}
      SECRET: ${SECRET}
      ADMIN_EMAIL: ${ADMIN_EMAIL}
      ADMIN_PASSWORD: ${ADMIN_PASSWORD}
      DB_CLIENT: ${DB_CLIENT}
      DB_FILENAME: ${DB_FILENAME}
      DB_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
      DB_PORT: 5432
      DB_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      DB_USER: ${DB_USER}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      WEBSOCKETS_ENABLED: true

    depends_on:
      - db
```

and my Django logic :

```py
def authenticate_user(request):
    print("function called")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        # Create a JSON payload
        data = {
            "email": email,
            "password": password
        }

        # Send a POST request to the external API
        url = "http://<my_domain>:<port>/auth/login"
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            # If the response is successful, print it in the console
            print(response.json())

            # Redirect the user to the given URL
            return redirect("http://<my_domain>:<port>/")
        else:
            print(response.json())
            return redirect('login_page')
    else:
        print(response.json())
        return redirect('login_page')
```

please note i have changed `<my_doman>` and `<port>` with the real data